# in my service, the method is defined to return a MessageContract but only return the first property

Tags: wcf

I have a method in the service that receive a messageContract and return other different messageContact with the results. This second messageContract, has meny messageHeaders.

In the contract I define my method to return this result messageContract, but in the client Visual Studio say me that the method return an Int64.

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the service reference by right-clicking to check the option allow message contract in the client.. Then update the service reference.. You will get